# Meteor Mongo update ($set object; $push array)

Tags: mongodb, meteor, mongodb-query

Good Day.

I'm having difficulty figuring out why my mongo isn't updating. Objects and Arrays are not being updated. I've 
been trying many avenues. Besides the code below, I've tried having the key already in the document (but empty, so 
the array would be `keyName:{}` , as well as the key not in the document). I've also tried putting the keys within quotes, etc.
I've taken the console output of the update and pasted into Robo3T and ran the query and it updates the document just fine.

meteor 1.6
mongo 3.2.15

Server code running

```
  const dbQuery = {owner: uid.user_id, paymentToken: uid.paymtToken}
  exFile = {
    $set: {
      agreement_id: responseData.id,              // string
      selfUrl: responseData.links[0].href,          // string
      agreementDetails: responseData.agreement_details, // object
      membershipLevel: 'premium',                // string
      ppOwnerInfo: responseData.payer,            // object
    },
  };
  let subsReturn = MonthlySubs.update(dbQuery, exFile, {multi:false, upsert:false} );
  console.log('subsReturn: ', subsReturn); // outputs: 1
```

This will result in the document being update with everything except the objects. I know that `exFile` is valid:

```
  console.dir(exFile, {depth: null});
```

results in:

```
{ '$set':
{ agreement_id: 'I-SW0AL8YJS',
      selfUrl: 'https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/payments/billing-agreements/I-SW0AL',
      agreementDetails:
       { outstanding_balance: { value: '0.00' },
         cycles_remaining: '1',
         cycles_completed: '0',
         next_billing_date: '2018-05-05T10:00:00Z',
         final_payment_date: '1970-01-01T00:00:00Z',
         failed_payment_count: '0' },
      membershipLevel: 'premium',
      ppOwnerInfo:
       { payment_method: 'paypal',
         status: 'verified',
         payer_info:
          { email: 'paypal-buyer@tion.com',
            first_name: 'test',
            last_name: 'buyer',
            payer_id: '99CEFGB6L',
            shipping_address:
             { recipient_name: 'test buyer',
               line1: '1 Main St',
               city: 'San Jose',
               state: 'CA',
               postal_code: '95131',
               country_code: 'US' } } } } }
```

Also having issues with updating an array.

```
  let pushFile = {
    $push: {
      links: {href: responseData.links[0].href, rel: 'self', method: 'GET', }
    }
  };
  console.dir(pushFile, {depth: null});
  subsReturn = MonthlySubs.update(dbQuery, pushFile, {multi:false, upsert:false} );
  console.log('subsReturn: ', subsReturn); // outputs: 1
```

Here's the `pushFile` contents from the console output:

{ '$push':
    { links:
       { href: 'https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/payments/billing-agreements/I-S45A17AV',
         rel: 'self',
         method: 'GET' } } }

This too works well in Robo3T.

I'm using `simpl-schema`:

```
[snip]
  selfUrl: {
    type: String,
    label: 'Link for details about subscription on Paypal.',
optional: true,
  },
  ppOwnerInfo: {
    type: Object,
    label: 'Subscriber name, address, etc. from Paypal. Populates after subscription executed. (payer)',
    optional: true,
  },
  links: {
    type: Array,
    label: 'Holds various Paypal endpoints. Optional because not all inserts/updates have these.',
    optional: true,
  },
[/snip]
```

Comment: I think that in your schema you need `blackbox: true` for `ppOwnerInfo`. Likely also for `agreementDetails` see https://github.com/aldeed/simple-schema-js#blackbox

Comment: That's exactly the issue. I never  noticed the change that @aldeed added to v2. Really wish an error would be thrown like any other top level schema element (type: String).
Michel-Floyd, if you make this an answer, I'll select it.

Comment: I agree - defining an object that has neither its own sub-schema nor blackbox set should error just on compilation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your schema you need to set `blackbox: true` for `ppOwnerInfo`. Likely also for `agreementDetails` see [docs](https://github.com/aldeed/simple-schema-js#blackbox)